How to create a course in Google Classroom from Flutter
I am trying to create a course in Google Classroom from an app in Fluter. I am trying to make a button, when clicking, execute a method, in which the necessary values ​​are already loaded, but it gives me the following error:
DartError: Unsupported operation: ServerSocket.bind

Everything that follows is the code
imports:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:oxxyweb/Functions/global/gloals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/classroom/v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';


method:
Future<void> createCourse() async {
  // Autenticación
  final clientId = ClientId('id', 'secret');
  final scopes = [ClassroomApi.classroomCoursesScope];

  // Obtiene el cliente autenticado
  var client = await clientViaUserConsent(clientId, scopes, (url) {
    print("Por favor, ve a $url e ingresa el código");
  });

  var classroomApi = ClassroomApi(client);

  // Crea un nuevo curso
  var course = Course()
    ..name = "Nombre del Curso"
    ..section = "Sección"
    ..descriptionHeading = "Descripción del curso"
    ..description = "Descripción detallada"
    ..room = "Aula"
    ..ownerId = "example@google.com"; // El ID del propietario

  try {
    var createdCourse = await classroomApi.courses.create(course);
    print('Curso creado con ID: ${createdCourse.id}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error al crear el curso: $e');
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
}

button:
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                createCourse();
              },
              child: Text('Crear Curso'),
            ),

I am using Google Chrome since I am testing from a web app, I have already enabled the Classroom API in Google Cloud, and I have been researching the information that Google gives, but I have not found a solution.
